# Price rules in Prestashop based on time

Tags: prestashop

I want to automatically reduce the prices on fixed time intervals. For example, all products older than 2 weeks get 30% off, after 3 weeks, 40% etc. I don't think I could do that using the built-in price rules module. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script in the PrestaShop root folder that checks when the products were created (`date_add` field in the `ps_product` table) and reduce their price (`price` field in the `ps_product` table) if they are `x` weeks old. It would look something like this:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . 'config/config.inc.php');
$db = Db::getInstance();
$discount = .3;
$weeksOld = 2;
$sql = "UPDATE ps_product SET price = price * (1 - $discount) WHERE DATE(date_add) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $weeksOld WEEK)";
$db->execute($sql);
```

Then you should configure a cron job to run it once a day.